# Scroll tableview and click in searcher crashes app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

I have a `tableView` which is showing the list of employees. Now when I Scroll the `tableView` and if scroll not stopped yet and if I click the search bar, app crashes. Index out of range. I don't have any idea why this is happening. Please, if anyone can help. Thank you so much in advance.

**Note:** Tableview is loaded with listArray. When user search, I am searchArray to show search result.

**Code:**

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchedArray = []
        searchEnable = true
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell:ListingCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ListingCell

        if searchEnable {
                self.setEmployeeDetailsInTableView(cell: cell, index: indexPath.row, dataArray: searchedArray)
        }
        else{
                self.setEmployeeDetailsInTableView(cell: cell, index: indexPath.row, dataArray: listArray)
        }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if (searchBar.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
        searchEnable = true
        getListForSearchedText(searchText)
    }
    if searchBar.text?.characters.count == 0{
        searchEnable = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchEnable = false
    self.searchedArray = []
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    getListForSearchedText(searchBar.text!)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

**Crash :**

> fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: Can you show us the code that's crashing please

Comment: Are you modifying listArray on click of search bar?

Comment: No, I am not modifying listArray.

Comment: @JeniKhant if you want help then you need to show us your code.

Comment: @JeniKhant You need to post more code.

Comment: @Nirav Can u suggest which method can cause this error so that I can post that code.

Comment: @JeniKhant Add other `UISearchBarDelegate` method that you are using.

Comment: what does your `numberOfRows in section` method have?

Comment: can you show code in getListForSearchedText method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you are setting `searchEnable` to `true` too early means in the `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_:)` so that as you said `tableView` is still scrolling, so it will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and because of `searchEnable` is `true` you are getting this crash. Now to solved your issue you need to set `searchEnable` to `true` where you are initializing the `searchedArray` array and reloading the `tableView`.

So you need to set `searchEnable` to `true` in the method `searchBar(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` or may be inside your method `getListForSearchedText`.

Comment: Thnx so much for answer, I will update if that's the problem.

Comment: Yes u r right @ Nirav, I just removed code in "searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)" func and now its working fine. Thank you. :)